# how to set correct batch_size and steps_per_epoch in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have 20000 RGB images. I set `batch_Size = 1` (due to GPU capacity). So now does it mean the model weights are changing with one-by-one pictures or it depends on the `steps_per_epoch`?

How should I set the `steps_per_epoch` and epochs for using all of 20000 images to be involved in training in different epochs?

Comment: it cant be a programming issue, please check the utilization, load on GPU. based on batch size it open a image it updates, moves on (stochastic gradient phonomenon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first clear some concepts:

- Each **iteration** is visiting a batch of samples in dataset.
- Each **epoch** is visiting all samples in dataset.
- **Weights** are being updated after each iteration.

How related batch size and steps per epoch to the above concepts?

- `batch_size`: Determines the number of samples in each iteration (updating weights). Minimum batch size is 1 (called stochastic gradient descent) and maximum can be the number of all samples (even more - read about `repeat()` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat)). There is another limitation for maximum batch size which is fitting to available GPU memory as you said in your question. Setting the `batch_size` to lower numbers makes iterations faster, but loss decreasing will oscillate more.
- `steps_per_epoch`: The number of iterations in order to consider one  *epoch* is finished. If you have a training set of fixed size you can ignore it but it may be useful if you have a huge data set or if you are generating data augmentations on the fly, i.e. if your training set has a (generated) infinite size with `repeat()` function. If you have the time to go through your whole training data set you can skip this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the weights are updated after each batch.
The `steps_per_epoch` should be the number of datapoints (20000 in your case) divided by the batch size. Therefore `steps_per_epoch` will also be 20000 if the batch size is 1.

Comment: Is it possible to reduce steps_per_epoch, on the other hand, increase the number of epochs for making the ability for the model to see the whole data?